# Compute $\mathbb{E}(X(X-1))$ where $X$ has a negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, negative-binomial

> Let's consider a Bernoulli trial where $p$ denotes the probability of success. A random variable $X$ that counts the frequency of failures until the $r$-th success has a negative binomial distribution. We can assume that
> $$P(\{X=k\})=p^r(1-p)^{k}{r+k-1\choose k}$$
> and
> $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}.$$
> Compute $\mathbb{E}(X(X-1))$. (We can assume that this expression is well defined)

---

**My approach:**

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}(X(X-1))=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)p^r(1-p)^{k}{r+k-1\choose k}=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(k-1)p^{r+1}(1-p)^{k-1}\frac{(k+r-1)!}{r!(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(k-1)p^{r+1}(1-p)^{k-1}{(r+k-1)\choose k-1}=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{r+1}(1-p)^{k}{(r+k)\choose k}=\dots.
\end{align*}

Now we see that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{r+1}(1-p)^{k}{(r+k)\choose k}$ is the expected value of another random variable $Y$ that has a negative binomial distribution. But $Y$ counts the failures until the $r+1$-th success and so $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{(r+1)(1-p)}{p}$. Hence,

$
\begin{align*}
\dots=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}\frac{(r+1)(1-p)}{p}=\frac{r(r+1)(1-p)^2}{p^2}.
\end{align*}$

---

The sample solution is $\frac{r}{p}\left(\frac{r+1}{p}-2\right)$. So I assume that my approach must be flawed somewhere. However, I dont see where I messed it up!?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your derivation looks good. There is a typo in the statement of the problem: the exponents don't look right, and as is the sum of $p_k$ is not $1$. However, even with this I don't think the answer would be the one you give in the end.

Comment: Even WA [agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28k*%28k-1%29*p%5Er*%281-p%29%5Ek*binomial%28r%2Bk-1%2Ck%29%2Ck%3D0..infinity%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm your answer is correct.
$$
\begin{align}
E[X(X-1)]
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty p^r(1-p)^k\cdot \color{blue}{k(k-1)\binom{r-1+k}{k}}
\\&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty p^r(1-p)^k\cdot \color{blue}{(r+1)r\binom{r-1+k}{k-2}}
\\&=(r+1)r\cdot \frac{(1-p)^2}{p^2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty p^{r+2}(1-p)^{k-2}\binom{r-1+k}{k-2}
\\&=(r+1)r\cdot \frac{(1-p)^2}{p^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{r+2}(1-p)^{k}\binom{(r+2)-1+k}{k}
\\&=(r+1)r\cdot \frac{(1-p)^2}{p^2}\cdot 1
\end{align}
$$
The final summation is $1$, because it is the total probability for a negative binomal distribution with parameters $r+2$ and $p$.

In general,
$$
E[X(X-1)\cdots (X-n+1)]=r(r+1)\cdots(r+n-1)\left(\frac{1-p}p\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just use linearity of $E$ to get
$$E\bigl(X(X-1)\bigr)=E(X^2)-E(X)=\sigma^2+\mu^2-\mu.$$
Now $\mu=r(1-p)/p$ and $\sigma^2=r(1-p)/p^2$ and we're done.

Comment: We don't know yet what value $\sigma^2$ attains...

Comment: @Philipp A negative binomial variate is a sum of $r$ independent geometric variables (waiting for $r$ successes is equivalent to waiting for one success $r$ times in a row). Therefore, the variance of a negative binomial is $r$ times the variance of a geometric variable, so as long as you know the latter, you can use Michael Hoppe's answer to get a proof.